# Continuing Donkey Kong 64 After Beating It?

Tags: donkey-kong-64

I recently played through *Donkey Kong 64* and am almost done it. I only have three golden bananas left to get—stupid “Beaver Bother”! I know that I can go and do the final battle with K.Rool without the remaining gold bananas, but I have read that there is a different ending if you finish the game with 100%.

Unfortunately, I have also read that if you finish “Hideout Helm” before getting everything, then the banana coins become ghosted and can no longer be gotten, so I am worried that it would happen with gold bananas as well, resulting in my having to replay *the whole thing* to get the alternate ending instead of just grabbing the last three bananas and re-doing the ending. This seems plausible because once you beat a boss (or get a gold banana, or pretty much any other goal in the game), it **automatically saves** the status, making it impossible to redo that goal in the main game.

Does anyone know if my concern is correct or can I see both endings without having to replay the whole thing again?

(Obviously if I were playing on an emulator, I can just load a previous state, but that doesn’t work on the actual console. I can also just watch it [on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=donkey%20kong%2064%20endings), but I would prefer to do it on the console.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you need both the Nintendo Coin and the Rare coin to get to the final boss.

But this is rather moot anyway, since the game does not save after beating the final boss -- beating the game does not prevent you from playing on that save file, since the last possible save point is *before* the final boss.

The "endgame", as it were, has essentially two parts - Hideout Helm involves completing the level before the Blast-o-Matic can finish charging, and after succeeding, K.Rool ejects, and you must chase him down to actually get your final boss fight.

I wish you luck on your quest for all 201 golden bananas!

Comment: `you need the Nintendo Coin to get to the final boss.`   I know; I'm wondering about gold bananas.     `the game does not save after beating the final boss—beating the game does not prevent you from playing on that save file, the last save point is before the final boss.`   That makes sense; most of the other SNES/N64 games I've played were like that as well. I'm just concerned because I've read in some walkthroughs that banana coins become impossible to get after finishing. I've stopped the Blast-o-Matic and banana coins are still solid, so maybe it's a bug in only some versions.

Comment: @Synetech And Bannana Coins have no bearing on game completion, either. The game only cares about the first 15 (to unlock Jetpac) and the % complete counter itself only counts golden bananas.

Comment: `Bannana Coins have no bearing on game completion`, no, but if they become unattainable after completing Hideout Helm, then other things like gold bananas (and the final fight) may also become impossible to get/repeat. That’s what I am/was worried about. I’ll find out as soon as I manage to finish the classic DK arcade a second time (I got oh so close twice yesterday). I figure the worst case scenario is that it makes me play again, but then I’ll just find a video on YouTube instead. `;-)`

Comment: I tried again and finally beat it. Indeed, when you beat K.Rool, it plays an animation, runs credits, then dumps you back at the starting screen. If you then view the save-game screen, it shows the same stats as before and loading the game leaves everything as it was. So it does not modify the save file after beating K.Rool, which means that you can indeed get the remaining bananas, then re-beat K.Rool to see the alternate ending in the future without having to re-play the whole game. (Personally, I don’t see that happening in the foreseeable future because *Beaver Bother* is a real @!#?@!).